# Turning on camera flash LED in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

so how do you turn on the camera's "flash" LED in Android?  (like flashlight apps) - and is it possible to vary the brightness?

search results for "android flash" too polluted by adobe flash :(

Comment: "Too polluted" results weren't helped by your title that I've edited, nor your summary ;)

Comment: Check out [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) and have a look at FLASH_MODE_TORCH I've also seen [a dodgy script](http://androidforums.com/incredible-all-things-root/102849-turn-camera-flash-led-off.html) that might point you in some directions.

Comment: Looks good.  For some reason it crashes trying to turn flash off in onPause but I can work on that.  Any idea about varying brightnesss? (hope this doesn't involve driving it with PWM!)

Answer (score 1):

check this topic, will help a lot.

[How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-only-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)