# Droid-X LED lights

Tags: android, led, motorola-droid

I can't seem to get the camera LED to light up as a flashlight with my Droid X. I've tried quite a bit, and am down to trying to decompile some apps that I know work. How can I get it to work?

I really think decompiling apps is going to be the only way for me to figure this out. :(

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763935/turning-on-camera-flash-led-in-android

Comment: Not really, there's device specific settings for the droidX that I can't seem to figure out. At least, things that work on other devices aren't working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OT?] − As a Milestone's (the european droid) owner, I have installed CyanogenMod 7 for Milestone and that (great) rom is packaged with the TorchRoot application. The flashlight works well on my rooted milestone…
Maybe http://code.google.com/p/n1torch/ could be a good start. From http://n1torch.googlecode.com/svn-history/r23/trunk/src/net/cactii/flash/RootTorchService.java, we can deduce that you need to be root to access the device.

Comment: I actually asked the writer of TeslaLED and he sent me how he did it. Thanks for this though, it might be able to help me out.

Comment: After I get it working, I'll be sure to! Haven't had personal time to work on it in a while.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found that works on the Droid X is the code presented by Siddhpura Amit part way down the page in this answer here: [Use camera flashlight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android). He checks the manufacturer and checks to see if it contains the string "motorola." If so, he has special code that can switch the camera Flash LED on or off. I can verify that it does work as I have a Motorola Droid X and this is code I use in my applications.