# Android turn on flash LED?

Tags: android, flashlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turning on camera flash LED in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763935/turning-on-camera-flash-led-in-android)

I need to turn on the flash LED in my app, and cannot find any simple methods. How would I go abouts doing this? I just need a sample code to turn on the LED. I do not want it to toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Camera parameters can be set to "Torch Mode", but as you probably know it might not work on all devices/OS versions.

Hope this question helps:
[Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH replacement for Android 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878294/camera-parameters-flash-mode-torch-replacement-for-android-2-1)

Comment: Didn't help, getParameters and setParameters were unfound symbols. Any other option?

Comment: Are you sure you have an instance of Camera set up?  That you got from public static Camera open()?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int).  getParameters and setParameters have been methods on Camera since API level 1, but maybe you're not using an instance of a camera.

Comment: This did not work, just caused a crash. Any other easy methods?

Comment: @t3hcakeman There is no easy way to reliably switch on the camera's LED light on all phones. There are quite a few phones, which need special handling to turn on the LED. Some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android?lq=1 and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android